# Android Java: Retrofit2 + google api auth with email and password gives 404

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, google-api, retrofit2

I've implemented auth with Firestore and it works fine and now redoing it via Google API and get http status "404" and empty message:

```
D/RESPONSE FIREBASE: Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/signInWithPassword?key=000080511101}
```

Network service:

```
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService instance;
    private static final String BASE_URL
        = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/";
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private NetworkService() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NetworkService();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public PlaceHolderApi getJsonApi() {
        return retrofit.create(PlaceHolderApi.class);
    }
}
```

Api

```
public interface PlaceHolderApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("accounts/signInWithPassword")
Call<Transaction.Result> loginWithEmail(
    @Query("key") String key,
    @Field("email") String email,
    @Field("password") String password,
    @Field("returnSecureToken") boolean returnSecureToken
    );
```

}

Usage:

```
    NetworkService.getInstance()
        .getJsonApi().loginWithEmail("000080511101", email, password, true)
        .enqueue(new Callback<Transaction.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Transaction.Result> call, Response<Transaction.Result> response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE FIREBASE", response.toString());
                Log.d("RESPONSE MESSAGE", response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Transaction.Result> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Documentation says that I should use Content type application/JSON, but how to use it here or pass it via http using retrofit?
Any directions will be helpful.

Thanks!

UPD: Console query result

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the docs/guide you're following to use the Google API ?

Comment: @FerVelvet https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue was because of colon symbol inside url ":", so url should start from dot and slash symbols "./":

```
    @POST("./accounts:signInWithPassword")
```

Found this on github and it helps https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2730

UPD: A little explanation why I used url like `"accounts/signInWithPassword"` with slash symbol inside instead of colon symbol: I tried with colon first, but got an error "Malformed url" so I dug a bit deeper with that mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header like this. But I think if you miss the header response, the error code wouldn't be 404.

Anyway, try this.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("accounts/signInWithPassword")
Call<Transaction.Result> loginWithEmail(
    @Query("key") String key,
    @Field("email") String email,
    @Field("password") String password,
    @Field("returnSecureToken") boolean returnSecureToken
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't works and still get 404. Seems like I'm using wrong url but what is correct url looks like?

Comment: i'm not realy sure but their doc URL not accounts/signInWithPassword it's accounts:signInWithPassword

Comment: That's true, but if I change url in @Post and set "/" instead of ":" - in this case got an error "url malformed".